# Create recurring profile programmatically in magento

Tags: php, magento

I'm working with magento and i  want to create a recurring profile for a new gateway , the problem that magento is supporting paypal only.

Answer (score 0):

Correct - recurring profiles are still in beta and PayPal is the first (and only) supported payment gateway at the moment (as of 1.7). [See here](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/working-with-recurring-profiles/).

To support a new gateway that accepts credit cards, you'll need to write your own payment gateway that extends `Mage_Payment_Model_Method_Cc` and implements `Mage_Payment_Model_Recurring_Profile_MethodInterface`.